# Bisection Method: evaluate a polynomial function

Tags: java, algorithm, bisection

I am implementing the bisection method, and as a first step I need to evaluate the polynomial function, but I do not get the correct result.

The polynomial used is `3(x^2)+7(x)+1`
with `x=2`, the result should be `27`

```
public static double evaluaFx(int []coef, int grade, int x) { 
   //int x viene siendo los x0,xf.xmenter code here
   double Fx=0;
   //System.out.println("grade"+grade+"x"+x);
   //for (int i = grade; i >=0; i--) {
   //   System.out.println(coef[i]);
   //}
   for (int i = grade; i>=0; i--) {
      Fx= Math.pow((coef[i]*x), grade);
      // System.out.println(Fx+"mas"+"("+coef[i]+x+") a la grado"+grade);
   }
   return Fx;
}
```

What's wrong with above algorithm ?

Comment: Could you add the arguments and expected output?

Comment: I used the next polynomial f(x)=3x^2+7x+1 with f(x)=27

Comment: rephrasing and formating

Answer (score 1):

Several things are wrong in your algorithm:

Formula for one grade (step `i`) should be:

```
 // for instance, if i=2, you want 3 * x^2 which translate to
 Fx = coef[i]*Math.pow(x, i);
```

Then in the for loop you don't add up successive grade computations, loosing at each step the previous result. You should do something like (note the **+=** instead of **=**)

```
 Fx += coef[i]*Math.pow(x, i);
```